# boost::variant implicit cast to string

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, boost-variant

I have a boost::variant with different types, where one is a (const) void pointer and another a string.

```
boost::variant<std::string, void const*>;
```

The problem is, if i want to use it with a c-string it casts it to the void pointer instead the string.

```
boost::variant<std::string, void const*> foo;
foo = "bar";
std::cout << foo.which(); // prints 1 -> void const*
```

If I remove the constness of the pointer it will cast it to the string.

```
boost::variant<std::string, void*> foo; // no const pointer
foo = "bar";
std::cout << foo.which(); // prints 0 -> string
```

Is there an easy way to make boost::variant implicitly cast the c-string to a std::string?

## UPDATE

I know I can cast explicit with:

```
foo = std::string("bar");
```

But I would like to avoid the explicit casting.

Comment: how about `foo = std::string("bar");`? see https://ideone.com/kgK2gm

Comment: @m.s. i'm sorry, i forgot to mention that i don't want to explicit cast it all the time. i will update my question.

Comment: With C++14, `foo = "bar"s;`?

Comment: It's worse then that. If you have a `variant<std::string, bool>`, and you initialize it with a string literal, you'll get a bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide your own variant template by inheriting from `boost::variant`.
The correct conversion from `const char*` to `std::string` is achieved through overloading the `operator=`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

template <typename... Types>
struct my_variant : public boost::variant<Types...>
{
    using boost::variant<Types...>::variant;

    auto operator=(const char* rhs)
    {
        return boost::variant<Types...>::operator=(std::string(rhs));
    }
};

int main() 
{
    my_variant<std::string, void const*> foo;
    foo = "bar";
    std::cout << foo.which(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs "0" as desired.

Live example: https://ideone.com/ZppUla

This idea could be even more generalized through the use of a traits class which specifies the type mapping:

```
template <template <typename> class conv_traits, typename... Types>
struct my_variant : public boost::variant<Types...>
{
    using boost::variant<Types...>::variant;

    template <typename T>
    auto operator=(T rhs)
    {
        return boost::variant<Types...>::operator=(static_cast<typename conv_traits<T>::type>(rhs));
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct conversion_traits
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <>
struct conversion_traits<const char*>
{
    typedef std::string type;
};

my_variant<conversion_traits, std::string, void const*> foo;
```

Live example: https://ideone.com/AXUqTv

Comment: Ooh, your solution is much nicer than mine. I'm deleting mine in favor of this one.

Comment: @Ike don't delete it, it is valid as well

Comment: Ah okay -- though I think this does a much nicer job and already generalized to work with any boost::variant instantiation -- nice.

Comment: unfortunately, i use vs2013 and don't have c++14 compliance. but i adapted your answer and it works. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a way to do this directly to my knowledge, but you could solve it with a wrapper. Basic one (to be embellished as you want and generalized as much as you want):

```
struct VariantWrapper
{
    template <class T>
    VariantWrapper& operator=(const T& val)
    {
        var = val;
        return *this;
    }

    template <int N>
    VariantWrapper& operator=(const char(&str)[N])
    {
        var = std::string(str);
        return *this;
    }

    boost::variant<std::string, void const*> var;
};

VariantWrapper bar;
bar = "foo";
std::cout << bar.var.which();
```

Doing it the above way will restrict the template matching to just literal strings and character arrays but still allow you to do something different with, say, `const char*`. Though you could just use `const char*` if you want to match everything that fits into the c-string category.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive your own class from `boost::variant<std::string, void const*>` and provide implicit const char* and string constructors.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved with `xnode` (class similar to `boost::variant` in some ways, similar to `boost::any` in other ways):

```
using namespace std;
xnode value = xnode::value_of("bar");
cout << "type: " << value.type().name() << ", value: " << value.get_as<string>() << endl;
```

There is explicit conversion path inside this class for string literals (arrays).

See: https://github.com/vpiotr/xnode